# symbol for true statement

Tags: notation, proof-writing

When writing little proofs to write a larger one, I often try to make a chain of $\iff,$ to get to an obviously true statement. I feel like it would be nice to do just another $\iff$ to an symbol that stands for "true statement," a boolean constant, if you like. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Casper's suggestion below, of $\top$, is standard.  [Wikipedia article about $\top$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(symbol))

Comment: Can you infer anything from the truth value? ⊤ ⇒ 1=1

Comment: This is the end of proof symbol: ∎

Answer (score 1):

You can use $\top$ for true and $\bot$ for false.

Answer (score 0):

*Note that I'm not going to provide such a symbol, but rather argue that it shouldn't be introduced in the first place.*

Something is never simply "true" without context. A statement can be true *if* another statement that implies the first statement is considered true, which is again only true if it is implied by a third true statement, etc. This chain in principle goes all the way down to the axioms of your theory.

In practice, however, one often stops (or starts) a proof at some well-known assertion. But introducing a whole symbol for just that part would probably just be confusing; instead, you should explain (with words) why that assertion should be considered true, or give some reference.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of a statement like 1=1, which I can assume is true without context in the environment I practice math at the moment. In principle, I could imagine that you are right and some quite philosophical implications might arise from your argument.

Comment: Let's say you arrive at a statements like $1=1$ in your proof. Then my point is that you should simply write, "which is obviously true, so we can conclude that ..." and not write some symbol next to it. It is a common trap for people entering more rigorous/proof-based math to think that more symbols means more formal means better. However, the goal of any proof is to convey some mathematical truth as *clearly as possible*. Obscure and specialized notation almost always hinders this; better to write it with words instead. Does this address your concern, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I don't think a symbol meaning 'true' or 'which is clearly true' is all that specialised. There is a symbol which denotes a contradiction (※), which can be used to say that a statement is obviously untrue.  I also think that English isn't necessarily more clear than math notation. If saying "which is obviously true" is fine, there's no reason why a widely understood symbol meaning the same thing, is not fine. Everything has and needs a context, especially normal language. Yes, if you would be resorting to an obscure, unknown symbol, that would obviously be inadvisable.

Comment: @lukeuser The problem, as I see it, is that no such widely recognized symbols exist, so you'd have to explain it with words anyway, and at that point, it simply becomes redundant to introduce the symbols.

Comment: Two general comments:  (1) This is pedantic, but I would avoid the use of phrases like "obvious", "trivial", or "clear".  These are contentless words, but come across as somewhat condescending in formal writing (and can you really say that "...which is obviously true" is any improvement over "...which is true"?).  (2) @lukeuser suggests that (※) is a commonly used notation for a contradiction.  I disagree---I've never seen that symbol before in my life.  I have seen $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$, $=\kern-0.6em\times\kern-0.6em=$, or a lightning bolt for contradiction.

Comment: In any event, I think that plain English is a better tool for conveying the idea.  Extra notation---particular notation which isn't really standardized anywhere in mathematics---hinders clarity, rather than improving it.

Comment: I agree with your latter point; a symbol which I thought was widely understood as meaning 'a contradiction', maybe isn't. I'm not sure why I mentioned that one, since I tend to use the lightning symbol (if any), but I take your point that there is likely no such symbol which is widely enough understood to be used without exposition (this also concurs with Dugnutt's comment).

Comment: Yet I dispute the claim in your first point, that words like 'obvious' are contentless. Certainly, it's very subjective and context-sensitive, what could be described as 'obvious'. But that doesn't mean it's not a useful concept. Saying 'which is true' without inserting 'obviously' conveys less information; the word 'obviously' is typically telling the reader that they should be able to make the final logical leap quite quickly and easily, relative to what has come before. Otherwise, it may be that some significant steps have been skipped for brevity (for example).